# Could we get a tag for the Reconquista?

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like to ask a question about El Cid but do not see a tag for the reconquista. Could we add a tag for the reconquista or should I use a different tag for this time period?

Comment: Kind of interesting really how much more interest there appears to be in the immediate post-Reconquista era (which was a short period), than there is in the Reconquista itself.

Comment: I believe an older discussion here went along the lines of 'the Reconquista' is a specific crusade for which the wider topic tag also fits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't consider myself an expert in what makes for a good tag. However, I think a tag should have enough call for its use to justify its existence.

After checking neighboring tags, [spain](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spain) (the most recent 50 of about 130) and [islamic-hispania](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-hispania), I only found one other question that would reasonably be better tagged [reconquista](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reconquista), were such a tag to exist.

Given that, I'd suggest tagging an El Cid question [islamic-hispania](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-hispania), and possibly also [spain](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spain) (depending on the amount of non Al-Andalus content in the question). When/if we one day get a few more questions specifically about the Reconquista, we can readdress the tagging.

Comment: The Reconquista is about `portugal` too.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - True, although it looks like in this case El Cid was dealing mostly with Aragon and Castile?

Comment: Sure. That is correct.